# Does compact convergence preserves continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $\mathbb{R}$ be the set of real numbers (with Euclidean topology). Let's think about functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. We say the functions $(f_n)_n$ compactly converges to $f$ iff for every compact subset $K\subset X$, $(f_n\restriction_K)_n$ converges uniformly to $f\restriction_K$.

> Is there a continuous functions $(f_n)_n$ that converges compactly to noncontinuous function $f$ ?

I tried on $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and proved that there are no counterexamples in $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Here's my proof:

If $f$ is not continuous, then there's a point $x\in X$ where $f$ is not continuous at. You can take series of points $(x_n)_n$ in $X$ such that $x_n \to x (n\to \infty)$ but $f(x_n) \not\to f(x) (n\to \infty)$. The set $A=\{x\}\cup\{x_1,\ x_2, \cdots\}$ is bounded and closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so A is compact. Therefore $f$ must be continuous on A, since $(f_n)_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on A.  This is a contradiction.

> Is my proof ok?

Comment: Is $X$ a subspace of $ \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @user251257 No. X is an arbitrary topological space. I tried when X is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, since I thought it might help solving the general case.

Comment: $\mathbb R^n$ is in many senses a very special space. The statement is true for locally compact space $X$. Your proof is correct if $X$ is sequential.

Comment: Your proof works in any metric space. But you cannot use sequential continuity in general topological spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $ X $ is compactly generated (especially if $ X $ is sequential or locally compact), a function on $ X $ is continuous if and only if it is continuous on every compact subset of $ X $, so your proof works.

However, there is a counterexample without any assumptions on $ X $. Let $ X $ be $ [0, 1] $ as a set, and give it the topology
$$
\{U \setminus C \mid \text{$ U $ is open in $ [0, 1] $ w.r.t. usual topology, and $ C $ is (at most) countable}\}.
$$
Then a compact subset of $ X $ is necessarily finite. To see this, let $ A $ be a infinite subset of $ X $ and take a sequence $ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ of distinct points of $ A $. Here $ \{A \setminus \{x_n, x_{n + 1}, \dots\}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is an open covering of $ A $ which has no finite subcoverings. Hence $ A $ is not compact. As a result, a sequence of functions on $ X $ compactly converges to $ f $ if and only if it simply (i.e., pointwise) converges to $ f $.

Define a continuous function $ f_n\colon X \to \mathbb{R} $ by letting $ f_n(x) = x^n $. Then $ (f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ (simply and hence) compactly converges to such a function $ f $ that $ f(x) = 0 $ for $ x \in [0, 1) $ and $ f(1) = 1 $. $ f $ is not continuous since $ f^{-1}((0, \infty)) = \{1\} $ is not open in $ X $.

Comment: The proof seems to be fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Continuity is a local question. So you can restrict your domain to a compact to study the continuity at a point $x$ of the limit.

As a sequence of continuous functions that converges uniformly on a compact has a continuous limit, then the limit is continuous at any point of your compact. This is truc for every compact, so the limit is continuous at any point, thus is continuous.

Comment: I'm afraid this discussion is not true. If you can take compact neighbor for all the point in $X$, the discussion seems to be ok. However, in this case, we're not assuming $X$ is locally compact. For example, $f(x) = 1 (x>0), f(x)=0 (x\leq 0)$ is continuous on every compact set $\{x\}$, but it's not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're right : what I stated is true only if $X$ is locally compact